# attempts left continuation countdown

Tags: excel, vba

is it possible to continue the attempts left? like on iphone, you can have a limited tries before it gets disabled. and if you lock the phone and on it again and try entering the wrong password it will still continue with the previous attempt number. for example in this code below i have set the counter to 5 attempts. then a user decides to enter the wrong password 2 times then giving up for a while before trying it again. the number of attempts now should be 3 even though the user cancelled it. until the correct password is entered then it resets to 5. is there any way to do it? thank you.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim x, z As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim mcounter As Integer
Dim attempts As Integer
counter = 5
attempts = 0

If ToggleButton1 = True And Sheet2.Range("J11") = "Status: UNLOCKED" Then
Sheet2.ToggleButton1 = False
GoTo looy
ElseIf ToggleButton1 = False Then
On Error GoTo ending
Sheet2.Range("I11") = "Status: LOCKED"
Sheet2.Range("I11").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Sheet2.Protect "3mice"
Exit Sub
End If

Do Until x = "3mice"
looy:
x = InputBox("Please enter password", "FOR ADMIN USE ONLY")
If x = "" Then
Sheet2.ToggleButton1 = False
Exit Sub
End If
If x = "3mice" Then
Sheet2.Unprotect password:="3mice"
Sheet2.Range("I11").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Range("I11") = "Status: UNLOCKED"
Exit Sub
End If
If x <> "3mice" Then
If counter > 1 Then
mcounter = mcounter - 1
counter = counter - 1
attempts = attempts + 1
ElseIf counter = 1 Or mcounter = 1 Then
GoTo disable
End If
z = MsgBox("Wrong Password", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "Error")
Select Case z
Case vbOK
GoTo looy
Case vbCancel
mcounter = counter - attempts
GoTo ending
End Select
End If
disable:
MsgBox "Disabled for 10 seconds.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
counter = 1


Loop
ending:
Sheet2.ToggleButton1 = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Forget about security when using Excel. It is too easy to bypass. If you want to do this as an exercise you are going to need to store the attempt count somewhere physically e.g. in a locked very hidden sheet with your VBE project also locked. Read write to value: initially checking its current value and doing whatever is needed if attempts reached else incrementing each time wrong and resetting to 0 if right (password).

Comment: oh. i see alright thanks. i mean honestly this is just en exercise for data logging and i hope that not everyone change so yea. it is not that important but hey it is still a good experience. also is it possible if i link you to one of my other post that needs help? @QHarr